# Installing CKEditor with npm

Tags: node.js, laravel, ckeditor, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am trying to install CKEditor in my project. I am using Laravel.

I know I could download the files but I like making my life difficult and I decided that I want to install CKEditor as a npm dependency.

As stated in their documentation [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_package_managers), I added the package to package.json, like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^1.11.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0",
    "elixir-coffeeify": "^1.0.3",
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    "ckeditor": "^4.5.7"
}
```

Now I guess I have to require it in my app.coffee, and so I tried:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('bootstrap-sass')
require('ckeditor')
```

This surely adds the ckeditor.js script to my app.js. However ckeditor seems to have its own dependencies such as config.js or editor.css, and of course the server responds with 404 for those requests.

How could I install CKeditor this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is probably a problem with paths to those CKEditor dependencies. I'm not sure if you are using browserify or something different but for example in browserify using `require('ckeditor')` will result in `ckeditor.js` (bundled probably with other js files) file loading from same dir as your `app.coffee` file while CKEditor dependencies are in `node_modules/ckeditor/` dir.

**To tell CKEditor from which directory it should load its dependency you may use [CKEDITOR_BASEPATH](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-basePath)**:

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = 'node_modules/ckeditor/'
require('ckeditor')
```

You may see if there is a problem with loading those files using **Network** tab in **Dev console** (e.g. **F12** in Chrome).

**Note that** it's not ideal solution for production environment because then you need `node_modules` folder on your server. You should probably consider moving only those dependencies to other folder during building/releasing process (and use **CKEDITOR_BASEPATH** as before with path to this *production* folder).

Answer (score -1):

Open the `resources/js/app.js` file

Add the following line:

```
window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');
```

Then execute the Laravel Mix command

```
npm run dev
```

HTML JS:

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
    <script src="[path]/public/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <div id="editor">
        <p>This is some sample content.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```