# ckeditor - Language JS files loaded from wrong URL

Tags: javascript, internationalization, ckeditor

I'm using the latest version (4.7.0) of `ckeditor`.

I installed it via `npm` and it lives inside a regular frontend (no fancy js framework).

**Problem: The translation js-file - im my case "de.js" is loaded from the wrong url.**

When I check the code I see the following in the code:

```
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl("lang/"+a+".js"),f,this)
```

Which add just `lang/de.js` to my current url instead of going to my static file folder.

My config looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
config.toolbar = 'Custom';

config.toolbar_Custom = [

{
  name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Styles',
  'Format', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'Image',   'Smiley'],
 },
];
config.extraPlugins = 'clipboard,dialog,uploadimage,uploadfile';
config.imageUploadUrl = '/uploader/';
config.uploadUrl = '/uploader/';    
};
```

I tried to add:

```
config.baseHref = '/static/ckeditor/';
```

and

```
config.path = '/static/ckeditor/';
```

and

```
config.basepath = '/static/ckeditor/';
```

But still, the code is loaded from the relative URL.

**Does anybody know how to properly configure the editor so it's not loading the files from a (wrong) relative path?**

Thx

Ron

**UPDATE:**

This is my config file, I add it via the `customConfig` parameter:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
 config.toolbar = 'Custom';

  config.toolbar_Custom = [

    {
      name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Styles',
      'Format', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'Image', 'Smiley'],
    },
  ];
  config.extraPlugins = 'clipboard,dialog,uploadimage,uploadfile';
  config.imageUploadUrl = '/uploader/';
  config.uploadUrl = '/uploader/';
  config.basePath = '/static/ckeditor/';
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`CKEDITOR.basePath`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-property-basePath) which defines:

> The full URL for the CKEditor installation directory.

So the paths for files loaded by CKEditor will be based on this config option if it is set.

---

You can also use `window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064972/installing-ckeditor-with-npm/36083620#36083620) for detailed description):

> It is possible to manually provide the base path by setting a global variable named CKEDITOR_BASEPATH. This global variable must be set before the editor script loading.

---

Any of this two should solve your issue, just use:

```
CKEDITOR.basePath = '/static/ckeditor/';
```

or

```
window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = '/static/ckeditor/';
```

The second one is useful when loading CKEditor by any module loader (like browserify). If it is not the case for you, the first option should be sufficient.

Comment: Ok, false alarm. I thought it works but still no effect on the server. Do you maybe have a plan b?

Comment: Do you have any browser console output which shows from what urls/path CKEditor is trying to load those files? Does using `CKEDITOR.basePath` or `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH ` changes the urls requested by CKEditor?

Comment: I have it now. The url ist just the current url, the basePath is not taken it seems. I'm going via "customConfig" and include a config file.

Comment: ok, was a problem with the serving of the static files. django-assets was the bad guy. Thx for your help!